# GitHub "Failed connect to github" No Error

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-bash

I'm pretty new to Git, but I've been using GitBash for commits, pushing and pulling for a week or two now. All was working fine, but a day or two ago when I started getting an error everytime I tried to interact with the remote repositories.

> > fatal: unable to access '....': Failed connect to github.com:443; No error

I've done some Googling and come across similar StackOverflow posts and articles. From that, I've tried a number of things, including testing the SSH connection across different ports (22 and 443). It looks like port 443 (for HTTPS connections) is blocked, while port 22 seems to be open.

[image: GitBash connection error]

From what I understand of this, it looks to me like I might need to change the port Git is using from 443 to 22. I've tried changing the `~/.git/config` file and I've tried the `git remote set-url` command to try to do this, but with no joy.

Any information on the original error or on how to change my Git port will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Port 22 is the port for ssh, and 443 is for ssl. Don't change between them. And the error you see when trying to ssh via port 443 is because of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any reason why you use git via HTTP? I'd suggest using SSH instead.

```
git clone git@github.com:GreenValley/GitHubSandbox.git
```

Comment: The two commands I needed were... git remote set-url origin git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git     and then...   git push --set-upstream origin master --force