# Git Failed Connect

Tags: git

I haven't found anything that matches my specific situation.

I'm trying to clone the angular-phonecat repository, but am having no luck.

I receive the following error message:

"Unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git/': Failed connect to github.com:8887; No error"

I have tried using SSH as this answer suggests, but that didn't work for me either:
[GitHub "Failed connect to github" No Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699802/github-failed-connect-to-github-no-error)

For that, I receive "Permission denied (publickey)."

I'm really not sure where to go from here.  I'm not sure if I'm blocked by a proxy/firewall, or I'm doing something wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is what I think is my .gitconfig files settings:

```
[user]
    name = tpa069
    email = noemail4u@nope.com
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[http]
    proxy = http://10.1.12.112:8887
[https]
    proxy = 10.1.12.112:8887
[gui]
    recentrepo = C:/Work/Testing/Playground/AngularJS/please
```

EDIT2: Found my own solution, or rather, my own problem.  I removed the proxies listed above and git started working great. I don't know if I should create my own answer and select it, or what the proper procedure is here.

Comment: Can you show your .git/config file? Also, was that last forward-slash intentional?

Comment: Github might be experiencing problems, or if you are at work maybe a firewall is blocking access.

Comment: Can you make sure that your firewall [allows outgoing traffic to :8887](http://portquiz.net:8887/); also, for the SSH solution you need to [set up SSH keys on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

Comment: also try to git clone a random project from elsewhere, i.e. gitlab.com

Comment: @BlackVegetable, I'm not putting it in there in my clone request, but the error message is returning it.

Comment: Ah, okay.  The .git/config file will be the most informative bit of information you could provide, I believe.

Comment: @e4thdog I plan on trying to use git bash as soon as I get home to see how it works there, I imagine it's a firewall issue.

Comment: @Sam: I have no idea how to do what you're describing :(

Comment: @Greg Burghardt: I found a .gitconfig file, but I'm not sure if it's the correct one, as these appear to be settings for Git Shell, not Git Bash (although both are receiving the same error.) I will update my question with the .gitconfig settings

Comment: Well, solution found, git doesn't like when you use a proxy you don't need apparently.  I removed those proxies from the settings and tried to clone again.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks for all your help everyone

Comment: @TParnelleJr. Could you list that as an answer to your own question?

Comment: As a user with under 10 reputation, I cannot for the first 8 hours.  I will when that time has passed!

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution, or rather, why it was my fault in the first place.

As seen above, I had proxy settings in my .gitconfig that I didn't need.  Git was trying to use those to connect, but since I'm not on the network where those were relevant anymore, it couldn't connect at all, and failed. After removing them, Git worked fine.

Don't try to use proxies when you aren't even being blocked in the first place :P